# Unable to connect mysql and getting socket error

Tags: php, mysql, linux, sockets, xampp

I have installed xampp in my linux server. But during connection in command prompt i am getting below error. Please help me to fix the error.

```
linux-pott:/opt/lampp/var/mysql # mysqladmin -u root -p status
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket'/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Comment: try `netstat -tulpen | grep 3306` on the console. This will print open/listening port of mysql if "online". You should see something like this: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  `. If you do not get any result, the mysql-server is not listing on the default port and so you cannot connect. Besides: This is not a PHP question in direct.

Comment: after running i got the output that you have said in upper.
bkash@linux-pott:~/Desktop/USSD/outputs> netstat -tulpen | grep 3306
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      60         96490      -

Comment: Okay then the server is up and listening. Try `mysql -uroot -pYOURPASS` (yes without spaces) just to access the server and verify connections are possible.

Comment: could you show us the log: /var/log/mysqld.log.?

Comment: @Serjoschaa:after run the command i got the error that i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Fernando Castilla:the log is in /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log directory
Here it is
150218 16:05:02  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150218 16:05:03  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
150218 16:05:03 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150218 16:05:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid ended

Comment: I think  It's not well install. Besides to show us the log, check the status of your mysql: sudo systemctl status mysql

Comment: Maybe is problem of selinux, show me the output of this command:grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow

Comment: @Fernando: AFter run linux-pott:~ # sudo systemctl status mysql
Failed to issue method call: Unit name mysql is not valid.

Comment: @Fernando:
grep mysqld /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow
No output

Comment: Try: sudo systemctl status mysqld.service

Comment: @Fernando: i have solved my problem. It was issue in socket path. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on a CentOS VPS. If MySQL won't start or keeps crashing right after it starts, try these steps:

1) Find my.cnf file (mine was located in /etc/my.cnf) and add the line:

innodb_force_recovery = X

replacing X with a number from 1 to 6, starting from 1 and then incrementing if MySQL won't start. Setting to 4, 5 or 6 can delete your data so be carefull and read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html before.

2) Restart MySQL service. Only SELECT will run and that's normal at this point.

3) Dump all your databases/schemas with mysqldump one by one, do not compress the dumps because you'd have to uncompress them later anyway.

4) Move (or delete!) only the bd's directories inside /var/lib/mysql, preserving the individual files in the root.

5) Stop MySQL and then uncomment the line added in 1). Start MySQL.

6) Recover all bd's dumped in 3).

Good luck!